# C program to count the occurrences of the letter "C" in a given string

Tags: c, for-loop, char, c-strings, counting

I need help with my program. Sorry that my code is a mess. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: What's the issue with your program other than it shouldnt build?

Comment: The last `if` does not make sense. Simply check `cCount` for being `0`. And add `else` clause to it.

Comment: `if (string[i] != 'C' && string[i] != 'c')` This won't do what you think. This is after the loop, so `i == strlen(string)` and you're only checking a single char. Furthermore, if string length == 50, this will check the 51st index invoking undefined behavior. Simply check `if (cCount == 0)`

Comment: Thank you guys, I knew that if statement was weird but I wasn't sure how else to do it. I feel dumb hahahh

Comment: Please don't edit the post to "fix bugs" (fix them in your actual code instead). That could turn all comments and answers into nonsense for future readers. I did a rollback of your changes.

Comment: Oh yeah true, sorry

Answer (score 2):

> Hint: while the user enters a string, you don't need to process the entire input as a single string. Use this to your advantage

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    puts("Enter text:");
    unsigned cs = 0;
    for (;;) {
        int ch = getchar();
        if (ch == EOF) break;
        if ((ch == 'c') || (ch == 'C')) cs++;
    }
    printf("The letter 'C' appears %u times.\n", cs);
}
```

Comment: I suspect the instructor's grammar is less than ideal and your interpretation is better than mine. Mine was to assume that each line of text is to produce a line of output. Yours is to assume only one line of output regardless of how many lines of input were given.

Comment: @JeffHolt: the code works for a lot of lines :-)

Comment: Yes, that is part of my point. But my interpretation is that "while the user enters a string" means "print output and continue processing so long as the user enters a line of text".

Comment: Ah! I see how I misinterpreted your comment. sorry. You're right --lol-- we've interpreted the problem differently.

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char string[50];
  memset(string, 0, 50);
  int cCount = 0;

  printf("Enter a string:\n");
  fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);

  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
    if (string[i] == 'C' || string[i] == 'c')
      cCount++;
  }

  if (cCount == 0)
    printf("There is no C's in the string.\n");
  else
    printf("There are %d C's in the string.\n", cCount);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `include <stdio.h>` in your post. And your `main` signature is wrong.

> **while** the user enters a string

If the assignment is to process until the user enters a zero-length string, then the following should work. But keep in mind it probably won't do what you want if the user enters a 50 character string, in which case the code will see two iterations of the while loop: one where the `string` has the 50 characters and the second where the string has a newline. It will be easier to see `fgets` behavior if you test with a smaller sized array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    while (1) {
        char string[50];
        int cCount = 0;

        printf("Enter a string:\n");
        fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);

        if (strlen(string) == 0 || (strlen(string) == 1 && string[0] == '\n') )
           break;

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {

                if (string[i] == 'C') {
                        cCount++;
                }
                if (string[i] == 'c') {
                        cCount++;
                }
        }

        if (cCount)
           printf("There are %d C's in the string", cCount);
        else
           printf("There are no C's in the string.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If, however, the instructor's grammar is inaccurate and the instructor meant "if" instead of "while", then the assignment is easier and not prone to problems induced by the behavior of `fgets`.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I had #include <stdio.h> but it didn't get copied with the rest of the code lol

Comment: @Steff You can *easily* post code. Just copy your screen, paste it into your post, select the code you pasted into your post, and press the `{}` button. Then look at the preview to see what you did.

Comment: I used to use `while (1)` for a looong time; only switched to `for (;;)` recently. I still consider myself a "`while` guy" though :-)

Comment: @pmg It *is* one fewer character to type. And read. Repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to that you forgot to include the header `<stdio.h>`.

The compiler should issue an error for this statement

```
if (string[i] != 'C' && string[i] != 'c') {
```

because the variable `i` is not declared in this scope. Its scope ends with the end of the for loop where it was declared

```
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {

            if (string[i] == 'C') {
                    cCount++;
            }
            if (string[i] == 'c') {
                    cCount++;
            }
    }
```

If the compiler did not issue an error then it seems you are using a very old compiler.

In any case the if statement above does not make a sense.

In the assignment there is not written that the input string shall be less than 50 characters long.

```
char string[50];
```

To count how many times the letter 'c' is encountered in the user input there is no need to declare a character array.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char lower_case_c = 'c', upper_case_c = 'C';
    
    printf( "Enter an arbitrary text. Press Enter to finish: " );
    
    size_t count = 0;
    
    for ( int c; ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n'; )
    {
        if ( c == lower_case_c || c == upper_case_c ) ++count;
    }
    
    if ( count == 0 )
    {
        printf( "There are neithr '%c' nor '%c' in the text.\n", 
                lower_case_c, upper_case_c );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "The letters '%c' and '%c' are encountered %zu times in the text.\n",
                lower_case_c, upper_case_c, count );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe better than `char lower_case_c = 'c';` is `#define LOWERCASE_LETTER 'c'` (and likewise for upper case)?